# Какие СУБД подходят для выборок записей, которые зависят друг от друга?

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, запрос, структуры-данных, nosql

Если, для примера брать реляционную базу, то в таблице необходимо находить записи которые зависят друг от друга определенным образом. Комбинации из нескольких записей  могут зависеть от других комбинаций из нескольких записей. 
Записей может быть миллионы.

 В реляционной СУБД это можно реализовать, используя определенное кол-во join. Но так как записей может быть миллионы, то после первого join, СУБД будет иметь дело уже с триллионом записей и т.д. И запрос в этом случае может обрабатываться неограниченно долго (уже проверено).
Возможно есть субд, предназначенные как раз для таких задач?
 Пока смотрю на графовые СУБД (neo4j),  но еще не разобрался, подойдет она или нет.
Посоветуйте, в каком направлении хотя бы двигаться.

Comment: *после первого join, СУБД будет иметь дело уже с триллионом записей и т.д.* Не надо рассуждать о том, что будет делать СУБД, если не представляете себе, что и как она делает.

Comment: Проверено кем, каким именно запросом и на какой СУБД. Почему вы думаете, что вам удалось сделать идеальный по производительности запрос для вашей задачи и собственно построить БД подходящую для ее решения ? И почему вы считаете, что вам нужно объединять все данные с помощью join, существуют разные подходы к решению одних и тех же задач. И откуда триллионы записей, если подборка идет по правильно построенному индексу, то по нему join сходу берет записи подходящие точно под ваше условие, не пересматривая весь набор.

Comment: И кстати, про триллион я вам сказал, но это было в ответ на один единственный комментарий, который касался одного конкретного join. И он означал лишь, что надо искать другое решение, не плодя многочисленные join в запросе. Возможно надо было применить какие то оконные функции или рекурсивный запрос, но так, что бы он работал по индексу.

Comment: P.S. лично я бы вообще не рассматривал СУБД написанные на java. потому что java и быстрая обработка миллионов записей не совместимы

Comment: На вопрос "_Посоветуйте, в каком направлении хотя бы двигаться_" могу ответить, что двигаться надо в сторону точной формулировки и формализации задачи. Вы задаете уже 3 подряд вопрос, но так и не описали четко задачу. Невозможно найти средство решения задачи не поняв ее до конца

Comment: Запрос: SELECT * FROM table join table as t2 on test.id<t2.id. 
table - это выборка где 2 простых условия where, т.е. со знаками ><. В выборке 100 000 записей. 
Проверял в СУБД Mysql. Прождав минут 10 результата я не получил. На более маленькой выборке в 1000 записей отрабатывает за несколько секунд.
Исходя из комментария про рекурсию я понял, что этот первый join все равно нужно сделать.

Comment: В данном вопросе идет ссылка на вопрос [link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769111/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0?noredirect=1#comment1200435_769111)

Comment: В задаче необходимо сначала получить разницу между значением записей. Т.е. для каждой записи получить разницу со всеми остальными записями. И в дальнейшем эти разницы анализировать.

Comment: @Николай Что за 2 простых условия в where ? я пока вижу только id < id, что из 100к записей делает несколько млрд записей. Если у вас те условия, что в where недостаточно сужают выборку или не могут работать по индексам то конечно вы не получите ответ очень долго. Покажите реальные условия которые задаются для 3-4 критериев. у вас в том вопросе есть пример вывода данных, но не написано почему результат именно такой, а не какой то другой, ведь там под условие может попасть гораздо больше вариантов пересечения, но в итоге их не видно

Comment: И замечу, что чудес не бывает. Если ваши данные потенциально создают миллиарды вариантов и для решения задачи требуется пересмотреть все варианты это будет очень долго. Вне зависимости от того, на чем вы будете это решать. Надо искать путь при котором миллиарды пересматривать не надо. Так что сначала надо придумать алгоритм по которому с помощью бумаги и карандаша можно было найти требуемое. Если такого алгоритма не существует и требуется всегда полный перебор, очевидно у вас проблема, любой компьютерный алгоритм сам по себе не может оптимизировать перебор, пока вы сами ему не скажете как

Comment: @Mike, в выборке с where (эту выборку я обозначил table) я получаю исходные данные для задачи. Эту выборку(с where) учитывать не обязательно, т.к. эти данные можно поместить в отдельную таблицу, поэтому не обращайте на нее внимания. Вы просто просили написать запрос, который я использую, я и написал.

Comment: В том вопросе я пояснил, что указал не все комбинации в таблице и на графике. Это для того, чтобы не захламлять график. Вы предлагали решение, судя по которому вы поняли задачу.
А что не понятного в условиях того вопроса? Критерии задаются пользователем и они могут использовать знаки *-+/, а также скобки () и условия ЕСЛИ, ИНАЧЕ. Но пока нужно хотя бы решить задачу без ЕСЛИ, ИНАЧЕ.

Comment: Насчет алгоритма я и так постоянно размышляю)
Если я приведу реальный пример своей задачи, то тогда точно можете не понять вопроса, т.к. там нужно знать специфичные понятия. Настоящая задача связана с анализом котировок.

Comment: Вот сразу бы написали, что это котировки. Может еще кто нибудь бы понял о чем речь. А то "расстояние", да еще до "объектов" очень сбивает. И теперь я более точно понял ... Ну у нас действительно проблема и любая БД сходу не решит по той же причине, что и любой другой алгоритм. требуется перебор. Причем по хорошему основная проблема в первом join, потому что у нас нет никаких предположений относительно расстояния между первыми двумя точками. Следующие точки искать гораздо проще. зная расстояние A-B и условие что следующая точка в 2 раза дальше, мы просто ищем точки с (A-B)*2 по индексу

Comment: значит нам надо накладывать некие граничные условия на первую связку. Например у нас условие C=(A-B)*2. значит посмотрев в БД максимальное расстояние мы можем сказать, что `(A-B) < max/2`и `(A-B) > min/2` значит `B > A-max/2` (если ничего не напутал со знаками). просмотрев все заданные условия мы возможно сможем сильно сузить круг поиска. Далее, нам для начала анализа не нужны все точки, достаточно уникальных точек (правда боюсь их не намного меньше, чем точек всего)

Comment: А если у нас еще будут отдельно собраны сведения об окнах значений на промежутках времени, мы можем дополнительно накладывать ограничения по этому самому времени, скажем мы знаем что показатель вырос до X только в 2017 году, а до этого он всегда был Y. Значит при начальной точке (A) где то в 2015, видя что максимальное расстояние по системе уравнений должно быть больше X мы можем не рассматривать как соседнюю точку к А все точки младше 2017 года

Comment: @Mike, Насчет граничных условий на первую связку, хорошая идея, не подумал. Попробую. А насчет ограничений по времени, то они могут быть, но с ними действительно проще будет, поэтому я о них и не упомянул. Пользователь может их не указать поэтому нужно рассматривать и самые сложные варианты.

Comment: Я так понял, математика и алгоритмы могут сильно упростить задачу. Поэтому, как один из вариантов решения, думаю попробовать написать ф-ию интерполяции по точкам цен. А затем уже анализировать свою функцию математическими методами. Только функция, даже из 100 000 точек, предполагаю будет очень сложной, но попытка, не пытка).

Comment: Я имел ввиду ограничения по времени не пользователем, а математическими методами. зная искомый диапазон значений интересующей нас точки мы можем быстро определить периоды времени, когда показатель был в этих границах и следовательно нам при поиске можно будет эту точку искать только в этих интервалах времени