# Как в PL/pgSQL вывести результат запроса?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Я начинающий в PL/pgSQL и попытался получить результат простейшего запроса.

```
DO $$ BEGIN select ID from eurusd_h1 END $$;
```

и

```
DO $$ BEGIN  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select ID from eurusd_h1' END $$;
```

Но результат не отобразился. Как отобразить результат (без использования функции, т.е. без конструкции CREATE FUNCTION)?
Для ввода/вывода запросов использую pgAdmin 4.

Comment: Никак. блоки pl/sql не предназначены для возврата из них результатов как из запроса. Максимум что можно это открыть внутри курсор для чтения запроса и вернуть его. Но из курсора вы так же не сможете читать как из запроса, вы сможете им воспользоваться в другом pl/sql блоке

Comment: А как тогда отобразить результат следующей функции:  'CREATE FUNCTION sales_tax(real) RETURNS real AS $$
DECLARE
    subtotal ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN
    RETURN subtotal * 0.06;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;' 
Пример взят из документации postgresql.
Вызываю функцию через 'call sales_tax(10.2);'  
pgAdmin 4 выдает сообщение 'Query returned successfully in 238 msec', а результата запроса нигде не видно, как вообще можно увидеть результат выполнения функции?

Comment: `select sales_tax(10.2)`

Comment: @Mike, Ура, получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: @Mike, получается, если из блоков pl/sql нельзя вывести результат, то они предназначены только для обновления/изменения таблиц?

Comment: в общем да. хотя функция может вернуть композитный тип, вроде строки таблицы и при этом один раз вызванная функция может возвращать результат несколько раз (см. return next), что позволит использовать такую функцию в качестве таблицы в запросе

Comment: я имею ввиду именно блок DO $$ BEGIN ... END $$; (без создания функции)
Он умеет выполнять то же, что и функция? Т.е., те же самые композитные типы вернуть может?

Comment: ему некуда их возвращать, клиент их не поймет. Да и не ясно зачем. Если надо что то получить, это можно сделать запросом select

Comment: допустим я использую курсор. его можно использовать только в функции и, я так понимаю, в блоке DO..END. Но функция/блок всегда разные. Она формируется на php и код функции зависит от введенных пользователем параметров. Т.е. на данный момент я постоянно создаю функцию, а затем ее вызваю и удаляю. А хотелось бы сразу выполнить код с курсором и получить результат, не создавая/удаляя функции.

Comment: Для того что бы получить какие либо данные курсоры вообще не нужны. Любые данные можно получить одним запросом. Курсоры могут понадобится только в случае обновления множества таблиц (и то для postgresql это не так) и в случае если обычный запрос невозможно написать оптимальным и он дико тормозит (что встречается крайне редко)

Comment: У меня как раз второй случай "если обычный запрос невозможно написать оптимальным и он дико тормозит", поэтому и использую курсоры

Comment: чего же вы там такое выбираете, у вас сотни тысяч строк и join по диапазонам ? Вы точно уверены, что это невозможно выразить запросом ? "_Код зависит от введенных параметров_" - а может в функции в зависимости от параметров надо было поставить IF ? Даже при кусках кода, хранимых в таблицах, его динамическое выполнения в внутри неизменной функции обычно не проблема ...

Comment: " Даже при кусках кода, хранимых в таблицах, его динамическое выполнения в внутри неизменной функции обычно не проблема ... " Это как? В plpgsql можно выполнять код, который записан в таблице?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html

Comment: Это только для запросов. Я имею ввиду, конструкции if, for и подобные можно выполнить, если они хранятся в таблице? На подобии ф-ии eval в javascript или php

Comment: Хм. а их то зачем ? из таблицы можно получить значение и на основе него принять решение какой блок кода выполнять, а какой нет. И особенно интересно зачем надо их вообще выполнять в SQL. Если это расчетная задача, лучше использовать для нее внешний язык. А если задача связана с БД, то if отлично превращаются в обычные условия в запросе или в крайнем случае в case. А for обычно разворачиваются в генераторы строк и/или рекурсивный CTE. Вы бы задачу описали (лучше отдельным вопросом), может вам подскажут другие подходы к решению ...

Comment: Выполняю в SQL, т.к. задача связана с БД и нужно проверять все элементы. Я все пытаюсь решить задачу, на которую вы как-то отвечали. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769111/] (Ссылка) Вот собираюсь сделать курсорами.

Comment: Т.е., используя курсоры, можно избавиться от первого join, после которого запрос обрабатывает огромное кол-во записей

Comment: А чем курсоры оказываются лучше join. Если они обрабатывают такое же огромное количество записей, то они обычно медленнее join. А если за счет них удается как то сократить количество обрабатываемых записей, то видимо на join просто надо наложить некоторые условия, которые так же ограничат записи

Comment: Курсоры сокращают львиную долю обрабатываемых записей. В том то и дело, что условия накладываются только после первого join. Т.е. сравниваются комбинации (полученные после первых join) элементов друг с другом.